# uint16 to hex with 2 bytes using hi- and lowbyte in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, integer, hex, hid

I am a bit confused about converting data from a microcontroller. I want to send and receive Ints, therefore I have vor convert f.e.: 1100 to hex, which is 44c but I need split this into 2 bytes 44 and 0c because the controller expect the Low byte first:

> decimal: 1100 hex: 044c
>
> The controller awaits: byte[0x0c], byte[0x44] (in that order)

That really give me a headache, because I don't want to convert it to strings and split etc. I have the same challange when I reveive a message from the mc, because I receive the lowbyte first.

I am not used to this type of stuff in JavaScript and need some help.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a `byte[0xC4]` and then a `byte[0x40]`? It looks really strange to me the way it got handled, as it's neither LE or BE.

Comment: Also please note that if you need to work with pure js you'll have to convert the integer to a hex string. If you, instead, use node.js then you should head over to Buffers.

Comment: Hi, I am using electron, so buffers should work. How could that look like? @DadiBit

Comment: Unfortuanetly it is 0x0c 0x40. 0xc4 0x40 would be for the controller c440 which is int 50240

Comment: What if you need to write `0x1234`? How should the input be for the controller?

Comment: I posted an answer that didn't use strings and splits, but needs a little knowledge of bitwise shifting etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)s, an array of bytes in node.js that allow you to use some simple I/O BE and LE functions like these:

```
const buf = Buffer.alloc(2); //similar to malloc

const number = 1100;

buf.writeUInt16BE(number);
console.log(buf); //04 4c


buf.writeUInt16LE(number);
console.log(buf); //4c 04
```

If, instead you need to access exactly 4 bits at a time you'll need the [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/) operators (e.g. `>>` and `&`):

```
const GetNthNibble = (number, nth) => (number >> 4*nth) & 0xF;

const number = 0x1234;

console.log(GetNthNibbles(number, 0)); //4
console.log(GetNthNibbles(number, 1)); //3
console.log(GetNthNibbles(number, 2)); //2
console.log(GetNthNibbles(number, 3)); //1
```

Comment: Wow, I never saw the I/O BE functions so far! This is great and I am going to use it. But your second example makes no sense to me, as "nibbles" is never declared and just a small typo i think const GetNthNibble = (number, nth) => (number >> 4*nth) & nibbles; should be const GetNthNibbles = (number, nth) => (number >> 4*nth) & nibbles;

Comment: @Matthias My bad! I initially though to use a third argument `nibbles = 1` and use `(number >> 4*nth) & (2**(4*nibbles)-1);` to get n nibbles before the position. I believe it's a bit too much for some simple `uint16`.

Comment: @Matthias If it worked for you, kindly accept the answer :D

Comment: @DasBit That worked totally awesome for me. I refactored my NodeJS App along the Buffer doc from Node and it is much more faster that the native c# WPF Application which had a lot of libraries and shifting stuff in it. I am talking in that App with a Mikrocontoller via a HID USB device.

Comment: I don't know what you need to do, but it might help learning C/C++ for low-level stuff. I highly discourage mixing node.js and C/C++, tho.